# Using WP_Comment_Query to get comments

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, comments, hook-woocommerce

Ok so I'm trying to sort all comments associated with a post by the meta_key.

It currently displays all the comments with likes, but doesn't show the comments without any likes now.

Here is the query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_id' => intval($_SESSION['thePostId']),
    'meta_key' => 'cld_like_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'parent' => '0',
);

// The Query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query($args);
```

I would like it to display all comments, not just the ones with likes.
Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

> What you are getting is the WordPress default behaviour; If you are
>   ordering by a specific key then you have to make sure it exists,
>   otherwise WordPress will ignore that.
>   **Solution**: You have to make sure
>   when a comment is posted with that add the custom meta field with it; Using 
>   [`comment_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/comment_post) and [`update_comment_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_comment_meta)

Here is a code which will do the above task for you.

```
add_action('comment_post', 'wh_checkAndAddLike', 10, 2);

function wh_checkAndAddLike($comment_ID, $comment_approved)
{
    $like_key = 'cld_like_count';

    $comment_details = get_comment($comment_ID);
    $comment_post_id = $comment_details->comment_post_ID;

    //fetch like comment meta
    $meta_values = get_comment_meta($comment_ID, $like_key, TRUE);

    //if like meta key is not present then add a key
    if (($meta_values == FALSE) && (get_post_type($comment_post_id) == 'post')) //replace post with your post_type
    {
        update_comment_meta($comment_ID, $like_key, 0);
    }
}
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!